# LINQ TO XML Solution

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

```
<Root xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DataSourceSchemaConfig.xsd">
 <Node>
  <Name>Peter</Name>
 </Node>
 <Node>
  <Name>John</Name>
 </Node>
</Root>
```

How do I get List of Names?

I've was trying this, but it doesn't work, where is my mistake?

```
            var lists = from node in nodes.Descendants()
                        where node.Name.LocalName.Equals("Node")
                        select node.Elements("Name").First().Value;
```

L.B SOLUTION WORKS ONLY IF I REMOVE xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DataSourceSchemaConfig.xsd" from my ROOT tag.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? How are you loading the `nodes` variable (and what type is it)? With L.B's solution below, are you sure you're selecting "Name" and not "Node"? (although I still get the correct answer using both in LINQPad)

Comment: .NET 4. Strange but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(....);
 var names = xDoc.Descendants("Name").Select(x => x.Value);
```

--EDIT--

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(....);
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://tempuri.org/DataSourceSchemaConfig.xsd");
var names = xDoc.Descendants(ns+"Name").Select(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: For some reason your solution doesn't work. Enumeration yielded no results

Comment: It works. Have you iterated on names? or tried to add a `ToList()` to the end?

Comment: @WildGoat: If your xml is in a string variable you should use XDocument.Parse(xml)

Comment: even if I try this var names = file.Descendants("Name"); it will return empty list. I do have xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DataSourceSchemaConfig.xsd as attribute in Root tag, could it be a reason?

Comment: `XNamespace ns = "http://tempuri.org/DataSourceSchemaConfig.xsd";` would also work :P

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var lists = (from node in nodesxml.Root.Descendants("Node")
                     select new
                     {Name = node.Element("Name").Value}).ToList();
```

where nodesxml is your XDocument

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution (not LINQ but works, namespace agnostic):

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.LoadXml(xmlstring);
 XmlNodeList nlist = doc.SelectNodes("/*[local-name(.)='Root']/*[local-name(.)='Node']/*[local-name(.)='Name']/text()");
 var list = new List<string>(nlist.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(x => x.Value));
```

That XPath takes care of the DefaultNamespace issue, since you cannot use the XmlNamespaceManager to specify the default namespace.